# Synchronising client DB with Keycloak users

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

We are currently in the process of migrating our user authentication to Keycloak, using an OIDC server. The issue is that the architecture of some of our client applications rely on existing user tables, linked to numerous other tables throughout the services.

How can we go about keeping Keycloak users in sync with the client user, so that if a customer deletes or creates a user on Keycloak, it's reflected in that client DB? Is this generally done through overwriting OIDC methods?

Similarly, when a user logs in through Keycloak, we will require a lookup on the client DB to get additional attributes for the access token, such as the client userId and accountId for that user. Can this be done via overwriting the`transformAccessToken` method and making a request to the client BE?

Comment: Have you tried to implement your own IdentityProvider? It can be used to query additional attributes from external DB